# Pasar datos de un datagrid de un formulario a otro datagrid en otro formulario en C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente aplicativo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual al colocar la identificacion en el TextBox y darle Buscar, ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado en SQL y muestra el resultado en el DataGridView1.

Al darle al boton Form2, me muestra el segundo formulario con un DataGridView en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es pasar toda la información del DataGridView1 del Formulario1 al DataGridView1 del Formulario 2 mediante un botón.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Este es el código que tengo actualmente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cont = 0;
            //Los argumentos de conexion a la base de datos
            string args = "Data Source=adsysdb;Initial Catalog=Cumplimiento;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = args;

            try
            {
                //Indico el SP que voy a utilizar
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("paGenerarArchivo_SSRU_RequerimientoUrgente", conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);



                //Envió los parámetros que necesito


                //   valorconvertido = Convert.ToSingle(textBox1.Text);

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Identidad", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                param.Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();

                //Aquí ejecuto el SP y lo lleno en el DataTable
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                //Enlazo mis datos obtenidos en el DataTable con el grid
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                cont++;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                if (cont == 0)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("No se encontro el cliente ingresado");
                }
            }


            
        }

        private void btform2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 formulario2 = new Form2();
            formulario2.ShowDialog(this);
        }

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el segundo formulario creas un constructor nuevo que va a recibir como parámetro un **DataTable**:

```
public Form2(DataTable dt)
{
   datagridForm2.DataSource = dt;   
}
```

Este nuevo constructor definido por ti enlaza la **propiedad DataSource** del **DataGrid** del segundo formulario al **DataTable** del primer formulario pasado como parámetro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para construir el segundo formulario pondrías en tu botón del primer formulario:

```
Form2 formulario2 = new Form2(dt);
formulario2.ShowDialog();
```

**Nota:** este constructor es nuevo y lo creas tú, no hace falta que borres el constructor por defecto, una clase puede tener tantos constructores como desees y utilizarlos indistintamente según el caso.

Comment: Solo una consulta, todo este código iría dentro del botón nuevo que me pasara los datos al otro dgv?

Comment: El constructor nuevo va en el segundo formulario, lo otro va en el primer formulario tal como ya lo tienes casi hecho

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo en esto y no se eso de constructores, el primero iria en el public partial del formulario que va a recibir, y lo otro iria en el boton del primer formulario que va a enviar la data al otro dvg?

Comment: @MarcoTulio revisa lo nuevo q puse

Comment: Muy bien he colocado todo exactamente como dijiste, sin embargo me sale error en el boton Enviar que he colocado en el Form1, donde va ```Form2 formulario2 = new Form2(dt);
formulario2.ShowDialog();``` me sale este error   ```El nombre 'dt' no existe en el contexto actual```

Comment: Ese error te da pq tu datatable debe ser una variable global, declara tu DataTable como miembro de la clase Form1 y no dentro del Button1

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135606/discussion-between-marco-tulio-and-japv).